# getting Null Reference Exception while callBack in the response from 'GeoCodeService' using Bing Maps in Windows Phone 7.1 application

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, geocoding, bing-maps

I am developing a windows phone application in which I need to show the maps for locating two different locations and show the route between those two locations and also the directions.
Am getting the TO and FROM address line from the json webservice which I need to use for sending the request for locations to the "GeoCodeService".

To achieve the above I am using Bing Maps - 'GeoCodeService', 'GeoRouteService' and trying with the following code. While running the application I am getting a `NullReferenceException` while getting the callBack response from the GeoCodeService.

As I am completely new in developing Windows phone application, Am not using a complete MVVM pattern. However, I could get the data from the Json Webservice but then unable to get the result from the GeoCodeService to bind them to my map.

The following is my xaml code:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Map">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <maps:Map x:Name="bingMap"
                  Center="50.851041,4.361572"
                  ZoomLevel="10"
                  CredentialsProvider="{StaticResource MapCredentials}">
            <maps:MapPolyline Locations="{Binding RoutePoints, Converter={StaticResource locationConverter}}"
                  Stroke="#FF0000FF"
                  StrokeThickness="5" />
            <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding StartPoint, Converter={StaticResource locationConverter}}"
                  Content="Start" />
            <maps:Pushpin Location="{Binding EndPoint, Converter={StaticResource locationConverter}}"
                  Content="End" />
        </maps:Map>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Button Margin="80,0,0,0"
                    x:Name="btnputodo"
                    Click="btnputodo_Click"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    FontFamily="Verdana"
                    FontSize="18"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    Height="60"
                    Content="Pu to Do"
                    Width="150"
                    Background="White"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnmyloctopu"
                    Click="btnmyloctopu_Click"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    FontFamily="Verdana"
                    FontSize="18"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                    Height="60"
                    Content="Loc to Pu"
                    Width="150"
                    Background="White"
                    Foreground="Black"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</controls:PivotItem>
<controls:PivotItem Header="Directions">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Itinerary, Converter={StaticResource itineraryConverter}}"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItineraryItemComplete}" />
</controls:PivotItem>
```

The below is my xaml.cs code (the code-behind):

```
private Location toLocation;

private Location fromLocation;

private Address from;
public Address From
{
    get { return from; }
    set
    {
        from = value;
        Change("From");
    }
}

private Address to;
public Address To
{
    get { return to; }
    set
    {
        to = value;
        Change("To");
    }
}
private Location startPoint;
public Location StartPoint
{
    get { return startPoint; }
    set
    {
        startPoint = value;
        Change("StartPoint");
    }
}

private Location endPoint;
public Location EndPoint
{
    get { return endPoint; }
    set
    {
        endPoint = value;
        Change("EndPoint");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<Location> routePoints;
public ObservableCollection<Location> RoutePoints
{
    get { return routePoints; }
    set
    {
        routePoints = value;
        Change("RoutePoints");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<ItineraryItem> itinerary;
public ObservableCollection<ItineraryItem> Itinerary
{
    get
    {
        return itinerary;
    }
    set
    {
        itinerary = value;
        Change("Itinerary");
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void Change(string property)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}

public event EventHandler RouteResolved;

private void RaiseRouteResolved()
{
    if (RouteResolved != null)
        RouteResolved(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void btnputodo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    foreach (var dictionary in pickdrops)
    {
        if (dictionary.Key == "pickups")
        {
            locate = dictionary.Value;
            this.From = new Address();
            this.From.AddressLine = locate;
            this.From.Locality = this.From.AdminDistrict = this.From.CountryRegion = this.From.District = this.From.PostalCode = this.From.PostalTown = string.Empty;
            ResolveRoute();

        }
        if (dictionary.Key == "drops")
        {
            locate = dictionary.Value;
            this.To= new Address();
            this.To.AddressLine = locate;
            this.To.Locality = this.To.AdminDistrict = this.To.CountryRegion = this.To.District = this.To.PostalCode = this.To.PostalTown = string.Empty;
            ResolveRoute1();

        }
    }
}


public void ResolveRoute()
{
    GetGeoLocation(From, (l) => fromLocation = l);

}

public void ResolveRoute1()
{
    GetGeoLocation1(To, (l) => toLocation = l);
}

private void GetGeoLocation1(Address address, Action<Utils.WP7.Bing.BingGeo.GeocodeLocation> callBack)
{
    var geoRequest = new GeocodeRequest();
    geoRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
    geoRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = App.BingApiKey;
    geoRequest.Address = address;

        var geoClient = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
    geoClient.GeocodeCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        string statusCode =  e.Result.ResponseSummary.StatusCode.ToString();
        string ss = e.Result.Results == null ? "EMPTY" : "OK";
        if (e.Result.Results != null && e.Result.Results.Count > 0)
        {
            string dd = e.Result.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude.ToString(); 
        }

        // Am getting Exception at the below statement -->
        callBack(e.Result.Results.FirstOrDefault().Locations.FirstOrDefault());
        // <---

        LocationLoaded();
    };
    geoClient.GeocodeAsync(geoRequest);
}

private void GetGeoLocation(Address address, Action<Utils.WP7.Bing.BingGeo.GeocodeLocation> callBack)
{
    var geoRequest = new GeocodeRequest();
    geoRequest.Credentials = new Credentials();
    geoRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = App.BingApiKey;
    geoRequest.Address  = address;


    var geoClient = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
    geoClient.GeocodeCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        callBack(e.Result.Results.FirstOrDefault().Locations.FirstOrDefault());
        LocationLoaded();
    };
    geoClient.GeocodeAsync(geoRequest);
}


private void LocationLoaded()
{
    if (fromLocation != null && toLocation != null)
    {
        var fromWaypoint = new Waypoint();
        fromWaypoint.Description = "From";
        fromWaypoint.Location = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform.Location();
        fromWaypoint.Location.Altitude = fromLocation.Altitude;
        fromWaypoint.Location.Latitude = fromLocation.Latitude;
        fromWaypoint.Location.Longitude = fromLocation.Longitude;

        var toWaypoint = new Waypoint();
        toWaypoint.Description = "To";
        toWaypoint.Location = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Platform.Location();
        toWaypoint.Location.Altitude = toLocation.Altitude;
        toWaypoint.Location.Latitude = toLocation.Latitude;
        toWaypoint.Location.Longitude = toLocation.Longitude;

        var routeRequest = new RouteRequest();
        routeRequest.Credentials = new Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.Credentials();
        routeRequest.Credentials.ApplicationId = App.BingApiKey;
        routeRequest.Waypoints = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Waypoint>();
        routeRequest.Waypoints.Add(fromWaypoint);
        routeRequest.Waypoints.Add(toWaypoint);
        routeRequest.Options = new RouteOptions();
        routeRequest.Options.RoutePathType = RoutePathType.Points;
        routeRequest.UserProfile = new Utils.WP7.Bing.BingRoute.UserProfile();
        routeRequest.UserProfile.DistanceUnit = Utils.WP7.Bing.BingRoute.DistanceUnit.Kilometer;

        var routeClient = new RouteServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IRouteService");
        routeClient.CalculateRouteCompleted += new EventHandler<CalculateRouteCompletedEventArgs>(OnRouteComplete);
        routeClient.CalculateRouteAsync(routeRequest);
    }
}

private void OnRouteComplete(object sender, CalculateRouteCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result != null && e.Result.Result != null && e.Result.Result.Legs != null & e.Result.Result.Legs.Any())
    {
        var result = e.Result.Result;
        var legs = result.Legs.FirstOrDefault();

        StartPoint = legs.ActualStart;
        EndPoint = legs.ActualEnd;
        RoutePoints = result.RoutePath.Points;
        Itinerary = legs.Itinerary;


    }
}
```

Comment: Wait! I'm preparing your answer...sorry for the late but I did never see your question before!

Comment: Ok: take a look to my answer, and tell me if you need help! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is related to how you are extracting result data from your request.

First of all, I see you are checking if your parameters are `NULL` values in this way:

```
if (e.Result.Results != null && e.Result.Results.Count > 0)
    (... some logic here ...)
```

But I think it's better to do so:

```
 if(e.Error == null)
     // HERE YOU'D WANT TO MANAGE A REQUEST EXCEPTION
     // (FOR EXAMPLE AN UNPREDICTABLE PROBLEM OF THE BING WEB SERVICE!)
     // e.Error is an Exception class
 else
 {
     // Get the first result received:
     var geoResult = (from r in e.Result.Results
                     orderby (int)r.Confidence ascending // USE THIS CLAUSE TO SORT THE RESULT BY CONFIDENCE, OTHERWISE REMOVE IT!
                     select r).FirstOrDefault();

     // DO I HAVE A VALID RESULT?
     if (geoResult != null)
     {
         // I DO HAVE A VALID RESULT FOR GEOCODING!!

         // Defined a new point location for storing my information:
         Location currentLocation = new Location();

         // Set the coordinates:
         currentLocation.Latitude = geoResult.Locations[0].Latitude;
         currentLocation.Longitude = geoResult.Locations[0].Longitude;

         // Your problem was here:
         callBack(currentLocation.Locations[0]);

         // ...NEXT SOME SAMPLE CODE...

         // Set the point on the Bing map with a certain level of zoom:
         GeoLocationMap.SetView(currentLocation, 10);

         // Set the location of the visual pin on the map!
         GeoLocationMapPushpin.Location = currentLocation;
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps!